# Deploy c#.net windows application with Crystal Report in Client machine/PC

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have already a finished C#.net application with Crystal Reports, it is working properly on my machine. but when I already deployed the release exe file and configuration file. the client machine cannot run.
so i tried to install crystal report run-time and it works.

My Question: is there another way to include the required files so that I don't need to install the msi or runtime for every workstation to run my system?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: AFAIK, it is not enough to "provide some files". Crystal-reports have to be installed. So you could make an installer project with crystal reports as a prerequisite. That way you can have them installed if they are missing and skip if already there.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. but the problem with that approach is, every time that there is a modification, the users' need to re install the application again and again.

Comment: Define "modification" ...

Comment: I mean if there is a revisions on the system due to users request or bugs

Comment: Well, if you have "modifications" in your source code, of course they will have to update ... that's how it works with desktop apps. Modifications in the report files, however could be distributed separately.

Comment: my point is if you are using a compiled exe on designated shared folder  then you just have to replace the configuration files then the system will automatically updated on the workstations also.

Comment: If you are planning to "deploy by copy", though you circumvent the need to execute an installer. But that will also mean, you are likely to not use for example Registry entries etc. So an alternative to an installer could be to check installation of Crystal Reports on startup. **Or** if your application is actually a client/server architecture, have the reports generated on the server ...